# Make from a dictionary a list with specific values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm coaching multiple athletics that are doing for about 20 sprints a training. Every training is logged in a system I cannot change, although I don't need all the values in the system.

Suppose I have the following data, then I have so far:

```
data = {
1200: {'id': 152, 'start': 0.170, 'middle': 4.234, 'end': 9.170, 'painscore': 68,}, 
1205: {'id': 164, 'start': 1.127, 'middle': 7.354, 'end': 12.170, 'painscore': 49,},
1210: {'id': 152, 'start': 0.165, 'middle': 4.031, 'end': 9.234, 'painscore': 75, }
}

new_list = []
for x in data:
    new_list.append([])
    for k,v in data[x].items():
        if k == 'id' or k == 'start' or k== 'end':
                new_list.append(v)
print(new_list)
```

**QUESTION 1:** How to change the output to the right format I can work with?

> The output is as follows: [[], 152, 0.17, 9.17, [], 164, 1.127, 12.17, [], 152, 0.165, 9.234]
>
> However, it should be: [[152, 0.17, 9.17], [164, 1.127, 12.17], [152, 0.165, 9.234]]

**QUESTION 2:** At the end of the day, I need per athlete an average score of the day. How can I merge all an athlete´s sprints into a list with an average value?

For example:

> Output at the end of the day should be: [[152, 0.168, 9.202], [164, 1.127, 12.17]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is in this line

```
new_list.append(v)
```

This does not append the values to the list you already inserted in new_list. You need to append elements to the last element in new_list, i.e.

```
new_list[-1].append(v)
```

An alternative solution would be:

```
data = {
    1200: {'id': 152, 'start': 0.170, 'middle': 4.234, 'end': 9.170, 'painscore': 68,},
    1205: {'id': 164, 'start': 1.127, 'middle': 7.354, 'end': 12.170, 'painscore': 49,},
    1210: {'id': 152, 'start': 0.165, 'middle': 4.031, 'end': 9.234, 'painscore': 75, }
}

new_list = [
    [v['id'], v['start'], v['end']] for (k, v) in data.items()]

print(new_list)
```

For the second part, if you are open to using an external library, here's a hint:

```
import pandas as pd  # version must be ≥  0.23.0

data = {
    1200: {'id': 152, 'start': 0.170, 'middle': 4.234, 'end': 9.170, 'painscore': 68,},
    1205: {'id': 164, 'start': 1.127, 'middle': 7.354, 'end': 12.170, 'painscore': 49,},
    1210: {'id': 152, 'start': 0.165, 'middle': 4.031, 'end': 9.234, 'painscore': 75, }
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index', columns=['id', 'start', 'end'])
means = df.groupby('id').mean()
print(means)
```

This will give you

```
      start     end
id
152  0.1675   9.202
164  1.1270  12.170
```

It should be easy to transform this into the form you want

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helped.

Answer (score 1):

You're appending to the outer list, not the inner list. Set your inner list to a variable like this:

```
inner_list = []
```

Then append `v` to the inner_list, like so:

```
inner_list.append(v)
```

At the end of your for loop, append the inner list to new_list.

```
new_list.append(inner_list)
```

Let me know if it works!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this kind of thing more easily using list comprehensions. This is the list comprehension equivalant of what you're trying to do.

```
[[v for k, v in data[x].items()
  if k == 'id' or k == 'start' or k == 'end']
 for x in data]
```

Nested list comprehensions like that produce nested lists.

But it could be further simplified to just:

```
[[x[k] for k in ['id', 'start', 'end']] for x in data.values()]
```

Answer (score -1):

For the first question, use list comprehension:

```
new_list = [list(v.values()) for v in data.values()]
print(new_list)
```

This outputs:

```
[[152, 0.17, 4.234, 9.17, 68], [164, 1.127, 7.354, 12.17, 49], [152, 0.165, 4.031, 9.234, 75]]
```

For the second question, create a dict of records of desired field values indexed by `id`, and then perform sum and division by record lengths over each item in the dict to obtain averages per `id`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
records = defaultdict(list)
for record in data.values():
    records[record['id']].append([record['start'], record['end']])
print([[id] + list(map(lambda s: s / len(record), map(sum, zip(*record)))) for id, record in records.items()])
```

This outputs:

```
[[152, 0.1675, 9.202], [164, 1.127, 12.17]]
```